# Trying to use filestream into another function but program termintes

Tags: c, file, filestream

I am trying to count the words of a file.I open a file into function and use this filestream to another but program fails.I should also note that the file is at the same folder.

```
void compute_stats(char words\[30000\]\[20\],FILE \*file){
int ch_counter=0;
int space_counter=0;``
FILE \*stats_file;
printf("Enter the filename that you want to save the stats\\n");
input_text(stats_file);
printf("This might take a while\\nPlease wait\\n");
int words_count;
words_count = file_words_count(file\);
fprintf(stats_file,"words count = %d",words_count);
words_array(words,file\,&ch_counter,&space_counter);
int unique_words = different_words(words);
fprintf(stats_file,"the number of different words is:%d\\n",unique_words);
different_word_lengths(words,stats_file);
printf("DONE!!!\\n");
}
```

i expexted the  functions that i call would work with this filestream but it fails

Comment: Your code has extra `\\` that prevent compiling.

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve]. Passing an uninitialized pointer `stats_file` to `input_text` and then using it later in this function is a bit suspect. You should run the code in a debugger and see where the crash actually happens.

Comment: Note that inside a code block, you do _not_ need to use `\\` to escape chars. You can place your code there and it will handle the original automatically.